# Snap-Apps on high DPI desktops

Tags: snap, hdpi

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 on a high DPI laptop. Gnome (more less) automatically scales applications to be (more or less) usable.

However, snap-apps (e.g. ubuntu-clock-app, keepassxc) are displayed very small, even the mouse pointer is tiny.

Is there a possibility to set high DPI settings for snap-apps?

Comment: AppImages of digiKam and Krita as well as some regular (GTK2?) apps like VLC Media Player and Master PDF Editor have very large fonts in menus, etc. Theye are quite usable but very odd-looking.

Answer (score 3):

You can (at least temporarily, until the app's next update, then you might have to do this again) solve this by adding `--force-device-scale-factor=2` as a command line parameter.

This can be done by editing the specific app's (e.g. KeepassXC) .desktop file.
To find and edit it, follow those steps in a terminal (ctrl + alt + t):

List the files to find the desktop file to edit:

```
ls /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications
```

Open gedit as admin (`sudo` can't [EDIT: couldn't, at least back in 2018] open graphical apps on Wayland. If you're on X, you can also use `sudo` instead of the `admin://` pseudo-protocol), for example:

```
gedit admin:///var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop
```

At the `Exec=` line, add `--force-device-scale-factor=2` before `%U`

```
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop /snap/bin/spotify --force-device-scale-factor=2 %U
```

---

2022 Edit:

If this does not work, try `GDK_SCALE=2`, *before* the `/snap/bin/spotify`:

```
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop GDK_SCALE=2 /snap/bin/spotify %U
```

Comment: did not work for me as of 2021-03-05

Answer (score 0):

I'm asking myself this same question.
The KeepassXC and Libreoffice snaps for example have a very tiny mouse pointer. Primarily for LibreOffice this is an annoying issue, because when you use Write you never know where the mouse is.
Maybe this has to do with the graphic libraries that are used to build these apps. Anyway this is a problem on HDPI devices.