# Set QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2 for snap apps

Tags: snap, 4k-monitor

I'm using VLC which is installed via the snap store. However, I have an issue when viewing it on a 4k display.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to set the scaling for snap apps, as I may run into this again for others.

I tried this post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931667/snap-apps-on-high-dpi-desktops) so my desktop entry is now. .

```
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/vlc_vlc.desktop --force-device-scale-factor=2 /snap/bin/vlc %U
```

but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks!

PS. on Ubuntu 20.04